# Merge these two separate SQL statements into one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two SQL queries, both of which are nearly identical apart from the `WHERE` clause at the end, is there a way I can merge these two queries into one? I tried writing a subquery but nothing I tried worked. The first query generates a list of averages from the last 14 days worth of data and the second generates the list using the last 7 days worth.

```
SELECT 
   report.report_group  ,
   report.business_name ,
   round(avg( datediff(mi,price.price_date,price.valid_date) ),0) average_minutes
FROM archive.report     AS report
JOIN archive.allocation AS allocation ON report.book_name       = allocation.book
JOIN archive.position   AS position   ON position.allocation_id = allocation_id
JOIN archive.price      AS price      ON price.position_id      = position.position_id
WHERE price.price_date < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day,-14,getdate()) , 102 )
GROUP BY report_group ,
         business_name
```

...and the second is:

```
SELECT 
   report.report_group  ,
   report.business_name ,
   round(avg( datediff(mi,price.price_date,price.valid_date) ),0) average_minutes
FROM archive.report     AS report
JOIN archive.allocation AS allocation ON report.book_name       = allocation.book
JOIN archive.position   AS position   ON position.allocation_id = allocation_id
JOIN archive.price      AS price      ON price.position_id      = position.position_id
WHERE price.price_date < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day,-14,getdate()) , 102 )
GROUP BY report_group  ,
         business_name
```

Comment: agreed w/ @fancypants also you are missing a right parentheses after your CONVERT functions.

Comment: these queries are the same, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to put -7 in your bottom query? (I changed the second to -7, below). Also you are missing a right parentheses after your convert functions.

The query below splits your current third column into 2 columns, one for the 14, one for the 7. It will run more efficiently than running almost the same identical query twice and connecting with a union. It uses conditional aggregation to show the average for the last 14 and the last 7. The WHERE clause states the last 7, as it needs to be the lower boundary in this case.

```
SELECT report.report_group,
       report.business_name,
       round(avg(case when price.price_date < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day, -14, getdate()), 102) then
                  datediff(mi, price.price_date, price.valid_date) end), 0) average_minutes_14_dy,
       round(avg(case when price.price_date < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day, -7, getdate()), 102) then
                  datediff(mi, price.price_date, price.valid_date) end), 0) average_minutes_7_dy
  FROM archive.report AS report
 INNER JOIN archive.allocation AS allocation
    ON report.book_name = allocation.book
 INNER JOIN archive.position AS position
    ON position.allocation_id = allocation_id
 INNER JOIN archive.price AS price
    ON price.position_id = position.position_id
 WHERE price.price_date <
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day, -7, getdate()), 102)
 GROUP BY report_group, business_name
```

Comment: Why not use an OR instead in the where clause? WHERE price.price_date < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day, -7, getdate(), 102)) OR price.price_date < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day, -14, getdate(), 102))

Comment: @YanireRomero true, my guess is he wants to distinguish them, but he could so with a case in the select list, i'll edit

Answer (score 0):

I'll stick with the OR:

```
SELECT report.report_group,
   report.business_name,
   round(avg(datediff(mi, price.price_date, price.valid_date)), 0) average_minutes
FROM archive.report AS report
INNER JOIN archive.allocation AS allocation
ON report.book_name = allocation.book
INNER JOIN archive.position AS position
ON position.allocation_id = allocation_id
INNER JOIN archive.price AS price
ON price.position_id = position.position_id
WHERE price.price_date < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day, -14, getdate()), 102) 
OR price.price_date <     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day, -7, getdate(), 102))
GROUP BY report_group, business_name
```

Comment: If you had the -7 line but not the -14 the query would return the same result. The difference comes into play with the calculation of average_minutes

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
select
        report_group, business_name, days,
        round(avg(mi_diff), 0) average_diff
from 
(       
    SELECT 
            r.report_group, r.business_name, 
            case when pr.price_date < CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), dateadd(day, -7, getdate()), 102) then 7 else 14 end as days,
            datediff(mi, pr.price_date, pr.valid_date) as mi_diff
    FROM   
            archive.report r
           INNER JOIN archive.allocation a ON r.book_name = a.book
           INNER JOIN archive.position po ON po.allocation_id = allocation_id
           INNER JOIN archive.price pr ON pr.position_id = po.position_id
    WHERE 
            pr.price_date < CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), dateadd(day, -14, getdate()), 102)
) d
GROUP BY 
        report_group, business_name, days
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Or" in you "Where" clause likely makes the most amount of sense, but if you literally want to show both result sets in the same table then you can use a "union all". Now if you want to filter out repeating data between the 2 queries (i.e one query has the same result as the other, and you only want to show that once) then use a "union"

Heres the union all:

```
SELECT report.report_group, report.business_name, round(avg(datediff(mi, price.price_date, price.valid_date)), 0) average_minutes
FROM   archive.report AS report
   INNER JOIN archive.allocation AS allocation ON report.book_name = allocation.book
   INNER JOIN archive.position AS position ON position.allocation_id = allocation_id
   INNER JOIN archive.price AS price ON price.position_id = position.position_id
WHERE price.price_date < CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), dateadd(day, -14, getdate(), 102)
GROUP BY report_group, business_name

UNION ALL

SELECT report.report_group, report.business_name, round(avg(datediff(mi, price.price_date, price.valid_date)), 0) average_minutes
FROM   archive.report AS report
   INNER JOIN archive.allocation AS allocation ON report.book_name = allocation.book
   INNER JOIN archive.position AS position ON position.allocation_id = allocation_id
   INNER JOIN archive.price AS price ON price.position_id = position.position_id
WHERE price.price_date < CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), dateadd(day, -14, getdate(), 102)
GROUP BY report_group, business_name
```

Answer (score 0):

In [standard] SQL, all aggregate functions save `count()` ignore `null`. If you happen to know that, it doesn't seem like your query should be much more difficult than something like this:

```
select report_group  = rpt.report_group  ,
       business_name = rpt.business_name ,
       mean_14       = round(avg(
                         case 
                         when prc.price_date < convert(varchar(10),dateadd(day,-14,getdate()),102)
                         then datediff(mi,prc.price_date,prc.valid_date)
                         end
                       ),0) ,
       mean_7        = round(avg(
                         case
                         when prc.price_date < convert(varchar(10),dateadd(day,-7,getdate()),102)
                         then datediff(mi,prc.price_date,prc.valid_date)
                         end
                       ),0) ,
from archive.report     rpt
join archive.allocation alc on alc.book          = rpt.book_name
join archive.position   pos on pos.allocation_id = alc.allocation_id
join archive.price      prc on pre.position_id   = pos.position_id
group by rpt.report_group ,
         rpt.business_name
```